# Early Binding of PreImage in Microsoft CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The Microsoft CRM advanced developer extensions have gotten me a little spoiled with their early binding for calls made to CRM's webservices.

I'm writing a plugin right now and I'd like to access attributes defined in the pre-image.  All the examples cast the preimage as Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity which uses late binding to access it's attributes.  I dislike hardcoding all those string's for attribute names into my plugin and would like to find a method that avoids it by using early binding.

Here is an example of a cast

```
var preMessageImage = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity)context.PreEntityImages["MyPreImage"];
```

But I have to use late binding to access the properties

```
var myProperty = preMessageImate.Properties["MyProperty"];
```

Is there any way to cast this preimage to an xrm object that has all the properties defined using early binding so I don't have to hardcode all the property names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first use the crmsvcutil tool in the SDK to generate "early-bound" Xrm entities and include that code file in your plugin codebase.

I suggest omitting the 'DataContextName' command-line arg so not context is generated.

For more information check here on MSDN: [CrmSvcUtil on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx)

Next, you should use the `ToEntity<T>` method on the Entity class to get a strongly-typed specific entity.  More info here: [ToEntity on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326141.aspx)